# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError @onMessage when server receives message (GlassFish)

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359207/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-error-when-glassfish-server-receives-a-message) but I am posting a picture with exactly what I have:

[image]

[image]

Whenever the server receives a message, the console throws out this error. As you can see all of the JAR files are there. There are no errors with the

`import edu.sanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;` because otherwise Eclipse would show me. So what really is the problem.

I see that the compiler says that it didn't find this class: `edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/Annotation`. But in reality the import has `.` (periods) in it, not `/`. (Is the compiler looking for the wrong thing?) How can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: This isn't a ClassNotFoundException, it's a NoClassDefFoundException.  This can happen when an uncaught exception is thrown during a static intializer call.  Is there a caused-by in that stack trace?  Are you certain it's in your classpath?

Comment: @jgitter. I am certain its in my class path because if it weren't then it would give me an error right? I put the caused-by that's in the stack trace

Comment: ClassNotFoundException IS the exception you would get.  Add it to the classpath.

Comment: Ok I see what you are trying to say. How can I do this in eclipse. I went to build path -> configure build path -> libraries -> and added external JARs. Is this not the way to add JAR files to the class path?

Comment: Are you deploying this to GlassFish?  Did you package it into your artifact?

Comment: thanks. I got it to work (almost). Now its telling me this: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing file: tr.txt`                                        `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: tr.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)`  Well, the file is in the same folder. Any thoughts?

Comment: In what same folder?  Is it packaged in the artifact?  Where in the artifact is it packaged?  How are you trying to access it?  If you stick it in the WEB-INF/classes folder, you can load it as a resource.